# Building nanomsg for Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, nanomsg

I have nanomsg and Android.mk from [here](https://github.com/nanomsg/nanomsg/issues/316).
I try to build it for Android with Android NDK.
And I have error:

```
[armeabi] Compile thumb  : nano <= usock.c
In file included from /home/roman/work/Nano/app/jni/src/aio/usock.c:28:0:
/home/roman/work/Nano/app/jni/src/aio/usock_posix.inc: In function 'nn_usock_recv_raw':
/home/roman/work/Nano/app/jni/src/aio/usock_posix.inc:1112:8: error: 'struct msghdr' has no member named 'msg_accrights'
     hdr.msg_accrights = ctrl;
        ^
/home/roman/work/Nano/app/jni/src/aio/usock_posix.inc:1113:8: error: 'struct msghdr' has no member named 'msg_accrightslen'
     hdr.msg_accrightslen = sizeof (int);
        ^
In file included from /home/roman/work/Nano/app/jni/src/aio/usock.c:28:0:
/home/roman/work/Nano/app/jni/src/aio/usock_posix.inc:1151:16: error: 'struct msghdr' has no member named 'msg_accrightslen'
         if (hdr.msg_accrightslen > 0) {
                ^
/home/roman/work/Nano/app/jni/src/aio/usock_posix.inc:1152:46: error: 'struct msghdr' has no member named 'msg_accrightslen'
             nn_assert (hdr.msg_accrightslen == sizeof (int));
                                              ^
In file included from /home/roman/work/Nano/app/jni/src/aio/usock.c:28:0:
/home/roman/work/Nano/app/jni/src/aio/usock_posix.inc:1154:45: error: 'struct msghdr' has no member named 'msg_accrights'
                 *self->in.pfd = *((int*) hdr.msg_accrights);
                                             ^
/home/roman/work/Nano/app/jni/src/aio/usock_posix.inc:1158:41: error: 'struct msghdr' has no member named 'msg_accrights'
                 nn_closefd (*((int*) hdr.msg_accrights));
                                         ^
make: *** [/home/roman/work/Nano/app/obj/local/armeabi/objs/nano/src/aio/usock.o] Error 1
```

What is problem?
I hope anybody can help.

Answer (score 1):

On your Android.mk file replace your

LOCAL_CFLAGS with these lines

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS :=  \
    -DNN_HAVE_STDINT \
    -DNN_HAVE_CLOCK_MONOTONIC \
    -DNN_HAVE_PIPE \
    -DNN_HAVE_SOCKETPAIR \
    -DNN_HAVE_SEMAPHORE \
    -DNN_HAVE_POLL \
    -DNN_USE_POLL \
    -DNN_USE_LITERAL_IFADDR \
    -DNN_HAVE_MSG_CONTROL
```

and these two lines also.

```
LOCAL_COPY_HEADERS_TO := nanomsg
LOCAL_COPY_HEADERS := nn.h bus.h reqrep.h pipeline.h pair.h survey.h pubsub.h
```

For more reference check below link:

https://gist.github.com/kroggen/ff49ad06e78754068be6/revisions

Comment: Now here: [android-nanomsg-native](https://github.com/litereplica/android-nanomsg-native)